# Is there a way to reduce number of Swift code lines?

Tags: swift

I have just started to learn Swift and made a Roulette kind of app in playgrounds.

I have used `switch` and `case` control flow for the different scenarios and conditions.
It took me **156 rows** to do all the 36 possibilities that a roulette has and of course the red and black colors.

Is there a way to do it with a loop? Am I doing it wrong?

```
let number = Int.random(in: 0 ..< 37)
let color = Int.random(in: 1 ..< 3)

let NumberColor = (number, color)
let Red = "and the color is Red"
let Black = "and the color is Black"

switch NumberColor {
case (0, _):
print("The number is 0 and the color is Green!")
case  (1, 1):
print("The Number is 1 \(Red)")
case  (1, 2):
print("The Number is 1 \(Black)")
case  (2, 1):
print("The Number is 2 \(Red)")
case  (2, 2):
print("The Number is 2 \(Black)")
case  (3, 1):
print("The Number is 3 \(Red)")
case  (3, 2):
print("The Number is 3 \(Black)")
case  (4, 1):
print("The Number is 4 \(Red)")
case  (4, 2):
print("The Number is 4 \(Black)")
case  (5, 1):
print("The Number is 5 \(Red)")
case  (5, 2):
print("The Number is 5 \(Black)")
case  (6, 1):
print("The Number is 6 \(Red)")
case  (6, 2):
print("The Number is 6 \(Black)")
case  (7, 1):
print("The Number is 7 \(Red)")
case  (7, 2):
print("The Number is 7 \(Black)")
case  (8, 1):
print("The Number is 8 \(Red)")
case  (8, 2):
print("The Number is 8 \(Black)")
case  (9, 1):
print("The Number is 9 \(Red)")
case  (9, 2):
print("The Number is 9 \(Black)")
case  (10, 1):
print("The Number is 10 \(Red)")
case  (10, 2):
```

And so on until the code reaching case (36, 1) and case (36, 2) respectively

The result is ok!
I need to know if there is a shorter way to do the code, reducing the lines with a loop or something that I'm not aware of.

Comment: That's not how roulette works :) The number 11 is always black!

Answer (score 6):

Your entire code can be as simple as:

```
let number = Int.random(in: 0 ..< 37)
let color = Int.random(in: 1 ..< 3)

print("The Number is \(number) and the color is \(color == 1 ? "Red" : "Black")")
```

That's it. No need for the tuple or the `switch`.

Comment: Yep, though once he fixes his roulette wheel coloring logic, a `switch` statement might become useful again.

Comment: @Rob Probably. Since roulette has 0 and 00 and I think at least one of those is green. And each number is either red or black, not both.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, can you please explain the part -> "(color == 1 ? "Red" : "Black")"

Comment: @Mike See the [Ternary Conditional Operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID71) section in the Swift book.

Comment: and what about the Green option? the number "0"

Comment: @Mike Your question was about reducing the code that you posted which is what I've answered. It is beyond the scope of your question to provide a correct implementation of a roulette wheel (which is nothing like the code you posted in your question). You need a completely different approach that can't be simplified quite as nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your code to something like:

```
let number = Int.random(in: 0 ... 36)
let color = Int.random(in: 1 ... 2)

switch (number, color) {
case (0, _):
    print("The number is 0 and the color is Green!")

case (_, 1):
    print("The number is \(number) and is Red")

case (_, 2):
    print("The number is \(number) and is Black")

default:
    break
}
```

Now, clearly, on an actual roulette wheel, the colors and numbers are not independent like this code would suggest, but this is one way to simplify your code while still making the intent clear.